# I can't use the provide title feature in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to use the `<% provide (:title, 'home') %>` but a syntax error is returned. should I install a gem for it to work. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you're misusing the `provide` method. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: Get rid of the brackets or get rid of the space between provide and first bracket.

Comment: I've seen the use of the provide method in the Michael Hartl tutorial to attain a uniform title

Comment: And what's the syntax error returned?

Comment: @lcguida - It is common to use provide for page title like this.

Comment: @BroiSatse thanks man, that worked. appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby the parens around a method call are optional:

```
provide :title, 'home'
```

But when using parens there should not be space between the method name and the parens:

```
def add(args*)
  args.sum
end

add 1, 2 # => 3
add(1,2) # => 3 
add (1,2) # syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
add (1+2), (1+2) # => 6
```

In the last examples you can see that Ruby treats the parens as a single argument when there is a space - which is why it gives a syntax error.